# Fontawesome alignment is not perfect

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to use fontawesome as icon in some text (ul -> li ->i)

Image here
[image: Fontawesome and text align error]

I want to align them perfectly from left to right

I tried...
HTML

```
        <ul>
            <li><i class="far fa-envelope"></i>Inbox</li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Sent</li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-exclamation"></i>Important</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-file-alt"></i>Draft</li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-globe"></i>All Mail</li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Spam</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>Trash</li>
        </ul>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.sidebar ul li i{
        margin-right: 5px;
        float: left;
}
```

Comment: Try adding the `fa-fw` class for each of the `<i>`

Comment: Thanks bro, it works!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Give the icon a set width

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li i {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 1.5em;
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <ul>
            <li><i class="far fa-envelope"></i>Inbox</li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Sent</li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-exclamation"></i>Important</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-file-alt"></i>Draft</li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-globe"></i>All Mail</li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Spam</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>Trash</li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

a table configuration

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
 display:table-row;
}
ul li [class*="fa"] {
  padding: 5px;
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li><i class="far fa-envelope"></i>Inbox</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Sent</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-exclamation"></i>Important</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-file-alt"></i>Draft</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-globe"></i>All Mail</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Spam</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>Trash</li>
</ul>
```